# Windows Server 2012 default user: Administrator safe?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I was wondering if it's safe to keep/have a user named: Administrator.
Would it be more safe to change it to an odd name ? or it really doesn't matter anymore? 
(I remember a long time ago hackers would hack ms servers by using default names like: administrator)

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better safe than sorry. If anything at least it helps prevent against brute force on a known user account.

Plus it's super easy to adjust, so why not.

Not only should the Administrator account name be changed, but this account should be set to disabled. A separate user account create with admin rights if needed (before disabling Administrator account).